# Something cuts from my models

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

When adding the model circled, I saw that it was cut-off. When i zoomed out there was this dark grey pyramid shape thing that when i moved the models outside, they were cut off(disappeared). I have no idea as to what it is, because I can't select it.[image: the image]